# NServiceBus allows control over deserialization?

Tags: nservicebus, deserialization

I am trying to integrate a legacy application with NServiceBus by wrapping XML exports from the application with a NServiceBus "wrapper" which basically strips out namespaces and adds the  envelope and NSB namespace.

I have the basic solution working but only if the root element of the XML export exactly matches the NServiceBus message type name.

For example if the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Messages xmlns="http://tempuri.net/MyMessagesNamespace">
    <!-- Note: the "V1" -->
    <PolicyEndorsedV1>
        ...
    </PolicyEndorsedV1>
</Messages>
```

then my handler code can happily deserialize:

```
namespace MyMessagesNamespace
{
    public class PolicyEndorsedV1Handler : IHandleMessages<PolicyEndorsedV1>
    {
        public void Handle(PolicyEndorsedV1 message)
        {
            // All work fine!
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the export XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Messages xmlns="http://tempuri.net/MyMessagesNamespace">
    <!-- Note: the "V1" has been removed -->
    <PolicyEndorsed>
        ...
    </PolicyEndorsed>
</Messages>
```

this will not be deserialised. NServiceBus tells me *System.TypeLoadException: Could not handle type 'Beazley.Messages.Risks.Events.PolicyEndorsed'*, which is understandable as the only information it's got to go on is the name of the root node on the incoming xml.

I have tried to control the deserialization behaviour by adding some of the .Net Serialization attributes to my message definition:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PolicyEndorsed", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class PolicyEndorsedV1
{
    ...
}
```

but this is ignored because NServiceBus uses it's own serializer (called XmlMessageSerializer) and not .Net's own XmlSerializer.

So does anyone know how I can do this? I think it would be nice to have the option to decouple the Xml names with their NSB messaging counterparts.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `PolicyEndorsedV1` inherit from `PolicyEndorsed`?

If so, use `IHandleMessages<PolicyEndorsed>`, and `PolicyEndorsedV1Handler` will handle both types of objects.

For example:

```
public class PolicyEndorsedV1Handler : IHandleMessages<PolicyEndorsed>
{
    public void Handle(PolicyEndorsed message)
    {
        // Handles both PolicyEndorsed and PolicyEndorsedV1 messages
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, however this is not the case. There is no definition for PolicyEndorsed, only for PolicyEndorsedV1. My question is about how do I make the XML I am receiving from my legacy application "map" to the PolicyEndorsedV1 message type?

Comment: I may not understand the big picture, but it seems to me that if the legacy message (PolicyEndorsed) can theoretically be mapped to a non-legacy message (PolicyEndorsedV1), then you should be able to create a common interface. You can also add multiple `IHandleMessages` to your handler if you would like to separate legacy/non-legacy handler methods.

Comment: Marking this the answer because it was useful to me. However, I ended up getting the third party which provides the XML to change the root node to be in-line with our LOB messaging conventions. Thanks